Fix for AMP Error caused by the Imply script tag in nextjs App
Tag found outside the document head which is only allowed as a direct child of the document head.
Error:
Invalid attribute: data-amp-bind
Fix:
Ensure that you are using only allowed attributes for AMP components. If you're using custom attributes, they should be part of the AMP component's documentation.
JavaScript Errors
Error:
Custom JavaScript not allowed
enter image description here
export const AmpImplyTracking = () => {
const url = 'ua.google.com';
const encodedUrlUA = encodeURIComponent(url);

    return (
        <script id="amp-access" type="application/json" 
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={
                { __html: `
                    {
                        "authorization" : "https://${encodedUrlUA}/api/resolve/genfpamp?channel=2&source=5&fpid=READER_ID&requrl=SOURCE_URL&reqref=DOCUMENT_REFERRER&host=indianexpress.com",
                        "noPingback": true,
                        "authorizationFallbackResponse": {
                                "error": true
                        },
                        "namespace": "usercapturing"
                    }
                `}
            }
        />
    )
}

